# Creating Project Fails in Visual Studio 2005 and VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Every time I try to create a new project or solution in visual studio (2005 and 2008), I get an error saying, "Project Creation failed."  I even tried running vs in administrative mode, but I still get the same answer. Anyone have any suggestions, in short of uninstalling all of VS and reinstalling it?

Comment: What kind of Project? Please state at least language (C++, C#, ...) and what the Project is called.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an Add-in behaving badly.  Can you launch it in safe mode?

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the blue i would guess a security/rights issue, eg. trying to create the solution on a drive/folder you don't have write access to, or has otherwise restricted rights.

Answer (score 0):

Is it in Vista, I know 2005 is known to have compatibility issues in Vista, dunno about 2008, but do they both have current updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in administrator mode, and click run as administrator and have all the latest updates and no add-ins, I think you might have to reinstall it.  Make sure you select all the development types you plan to use to get the sdks and not just the redistributables.

If that doesn't work, you might talk to the microsoft reps.  With some quick online research people really only had probelms like this before Visual Studio SP1, anything with 64 bit Vista has just been unable to compile ASP.

Good luck.